# Add figure to the Appendix

Tags: graphics, appendices

I am trying to add some figures (class diagrams and sequence diagrams) to the appendix but I dont know how can I include them in the appendix part. How can I include them to the Appendix part in this template below?

**Latex Template from the university**

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    german,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    BCOR8.25mm,
    DIV10,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}
\include{commands}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\frontmatter



%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Frontpage
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \input{0-titlepage.tex}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% list of contents
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The actual content
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \include{1-introduction}    

    \include{6-conclustion}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Appendix
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \appendix

        \listoffigures

        \listoftables

        \lstlistoflistings

        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    %using: \abk{Abk.}{Abkürzung}
        \printnomenclature

        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

    \printindex



\end{document}
```

**Figure example:**

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=200px]{images/injection}
    \caption{Class diagram of injection procedure in the service provider. }
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
```

**Edit:**
When I added them normal as this

```
    \appendix

        \listoffigures

        \listoftables

        \lstlistoflistings

        \newpage

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=200px]{images/injection}
    \caption{Class diagram of injection procedure in the service provider. }
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
```

I am getting  `Listing` at the top of the page. I want it without Listing at the top.

Comment: Figures in appendix should be added on the same way as in other chapters of your thesis. What is your really problem?

Comment: @Zarko: Please see my edit code below the question.

Comment: Use `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage`. `\cleardoublepage\begin{figure}[htb]...`

Comment: @MrAsker, I do not know, what of habits in organisation of documents has your university. Usually the content and list of figures etc is on begin of bok or  on its and. If the latter is your case, than to`\appendix` should follow your figure, than, after `\clearpage` or \cleardouble page`  follows your lists, each preceded with `\clearpage` or \cleardouble page` (thatt it can start on new pages, but I'm not sure, if this is rule in your case).

Comment: This is a crosspost to [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,76644.html#76644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know rules, which you need to obey on composing your book (or thesis). Even your question is not very clear to me. So I only guess, that you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    BCOR8.25mm,
    DIV10,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\include{commands}

    \begin{document}
\frontmatter
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Frontpage
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \input{0-titlepage.tex}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% list of contents
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The actual content
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\include{1-introduction}
\include{6-conclustion}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Appendix
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cleardoublepage
    \appendix
\chapter{Appendix}% <-- this title should appear on page header
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Figure
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=200px]{images/injection}
    \caption{Class diagram of injection procedure in the service provider. }
\label{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
    \listoftables
\cleardoublepage
    \lstlistoflistings
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cleardoublepage
    %using: \abk{Abk.}{Abkürzung}
        \printnomenclature

    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{bibliography}

    \printindex
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \end{document}
```

Above code will generate Appendix on new od page, where will place your image, than on the next odd page will follows list of figures, etc. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: I have tried you version, the page between the last chapter `conclusions` and the `Appendix` is being cleared but at the top of the figure page is the name of  the conclusions chapter!

Comment: @MrAsker, now I guess that your like to change header of page, where you have a figure. I don't know, how the Appendix is defined in scrbook, but to change the appearance of header you need to ad `chapter` or `section` with desired name after `appendix` and before figure. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Just an FYI, this question has also been asked on [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,76644.html#76644).

Comment: @Johannes_B, I was not aware for `goLaTeX`, it seems to be nice "Deutschsprachige forum fur" TeX. Its  a pity that my knowledge of German language (which is worse than English)  doesn't allow me to participate in it. Anyway, thank you for this information.